# Flutter passing list to another class is always empty

Tags: list, flutter, class

I'am trying to send a list from class to another, but it's always empty, I have a class called Prochaines() which has a list named Items i wanna send it to another class which is called MesFavorisOn() and has it's own constructor

```
List<Item> arr;
  MesFavorisOn({required this.arr});
```

and i'am trying to pass the list using button click

```
     onPressed: () {  
            MesFavorisOn(arr: Items);
}
```

By the way the only way to access MesFavorisOn from bottom navigation bar , i have this on list of screens of my bottom navigation bar i'am not sure but i think the list is empty because of this

```
 List<Widget> _buildScreens() {
      return [
        ProchaineState(),
        MesEncheres(),
        MesFavorisOn(arr: []),
        Autres(),
      ];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to lift the state up.

1. Ensure your Widget that contains _buildScreens method also has `items` attribute / field
2. Ensure your Widget that contains _buildScreens method has new method called `updateItems`
3. pass `updateItems`to ProchaineState through its params, as a callback.
4. on onPressed method in ProchaineState, ensure it calls the callback `updateItems`

this is the basic of state management in Flutter. the disadvantage using this method, is all of the widget built inside _buildScreens method will rerender at the same time onPressed is triggered

if its needed, we may improve by using another library, such as Riverpod or Bloc

Answer (score 0):

Your `onPressed` doesn't really do anything, instead you could assign the `Items` to `MesFavoritesOn(arr:Items)` at `_buildScreens()`, then if you want to update the `MesFavoriteOn` with newer aditions to `Items` you can simply `setState` in your `onPressed`.

Comment: i understand, but the thing is i need to fill a new list from the list Items and send it to the class MesFavorisOn, the new list needs to be filled when the user click on add button

Comment: That's what `setState` will do, will rebuild the `_buildScreens`, thus passing `MesFavoritesOn` with fresh data. When you press the button, I assume the `Items` are already filled with the fresh data right ?

Comment: but the only way to do MesFavoritesOn(arr:Items) at _buildScreens() is to declare the whole list there,